# Ajax response is not executed in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using ajax in my Rails app. In my application js i have

```html
$('#request_name').on('focusout', function () {
       var clientName = $(this).val();
       $.ajax({
     url: "/requests/autofill/"+clientName,
 type: "GET",
   contentType: 'text/javascript'         
   });
```

So i am sending ajax request to requests controller action autofill.

Autofill method:

```html
def autofill
     @client = Client.where("name=?",params[:name]).take
 respond_to do |format|
      format.js
     format.html 
 end
end
```

And in my autofill.js.erb file I have:

```html
alert("hello");
$('#request_mobile").val('hi there');
```

(alert is just for testing)
What I want to do is to update #request_mobile id field with some values in my autofill.js.erb file. The problem is that my autofill.js.erb code in not being executed.
And here is the response shown in firebag:

```html
alert("hello");
$('#request_mobile").val('hi there');
```

But nothing happens, even alert is not launching. I don't know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: can you show some piece of log file with `ajax` request?

Comment: @Зелёный, Started GET "/requests/autofill/Jordane%20Koch" for ::1 at 2015-03-19 14:39:19 +0600
Processing by RequestsController#autofill as */*
  Parameters: {"name"=>"Jordane Koch"}
  Client Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE (name='Jordane Koch') LIMIT 1
  Rendered requests/autofill.js.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 7.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms). Is it what you asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I understand entirely what's going wrong here, but I can see some ways to get closer to understanding the problem.
First of all, I believe it will be better for you to use `$.get` instead of `$.ajax`. It's just a bit less complicated to set.

Second thing - you actually don't need the `contentType` param in the setup, 'cause it is not about the type of the return data, but the type of data you're sending in the request. The responce data type is set in the `dataType` parameter.

Third thing, even if `dataType` is set to `script`, I'm not sure it will be executed, so the best way is to do it manually if you're 100% sure about your safety.

In the end, here's what should work.

```
$('#request_name').on('focusout', function () {
   var clientName = $(this).val();
   $.get("/requests/autofill/"+clientName, function(data) {
        eval(data);
     }
   );
```

Comment: if in preview in firebag is see my js code does it mean that i was executed. For example in console response is see document.getElementById('request_mobile').value("test value"); code and in preview is see document.getElementByID(test value).

Comment: javascript code returned does not get executed by default (safety first), so all you get is a string of code that you can output or evaluate or whatever.

Comment: is there a way to execute that code. I am doing like that because of tutorails showing this method. For example on in railscast and one in Rails4 agile web dev book.

Comment: `eval(data)` executes the received code as I showed above.

Comment: thanks your solution works. I don't know why it didn't work for the first time, probably i had to restart my server. But now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on your client-side. When it receives the Ajax response, it isn't executing it as javascript. It is executing it as text.

Add return false; after ajax

```
$('#request_name').on('focusout', function () {
   var clientName = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
    url: "/requests/autofill/"+clientName,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'text/javascript'         
   });
   return false;
});
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Should my alert() call launch?